# News Page default thumbnail not displaying in Modern News Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

Whenever someone adds a News Item, but does not select a different thumbnail and leaves the default one in, the default thumbnail does not display in the News Webpart. I can see it there in the news item and the Banner Image URL leads to it, but it's not displaying in the webpart itself.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can also reproduce this scenario on my tenant. I think it is by default and have no way to change it. Also I found that if you create a news page using a template "saved on this site", the default thumbnail will display in the News web part then.

[image]

you can share your idea here: [SharePoint User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/). It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products. What's more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.